# unexpected T_STRING in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
/**
*
* @ Author   : AtakanCan 
*
**/

error_reporting(0);
$install_directory_name = 'idevaffiliate';

if (!isset( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] )) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 
    str_replace( '\' , '/' , 
    substr
    ( 
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 -
    strlen( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ) );
} 
else {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

$path = $path . '/' . $install_directory_name;
include( $path . '/API/data.php' );
?>
```

I get the T_string error on the below line. I don't know what is the error behind this, please someone let me know.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 -
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting answers your question ...

Comment: Another note: disabling the error reporting is not helpful wenn you try to debug code.

Answer (score 2):

You have an escaping issue.

In your `str_replace` you have `'\'` as the first parameter. The `\` escapes the closing quote. Replace it with `'\\'` instead, to search for a literal `\`.

Comment: thanks for ur kind help sir. after updating as u said the website becomes blank..what should i do now